# How to combine imagedatastores for training two-input neural network on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network, datastore

I have two sets of 58 images each which I have to feed as input to a multiple-input network.

To do so, I first read each of the sets onto a different Image Datastore, as shown on the images

Reading the first dataset:

[image]

And then, the second dataset:

[image]

Then I merge the two datastores by using 'combine'. However, according to the documentation available here, I should be reading a three-column cell array, wherein the third column would be the labels. I get only two columns when reading though:

[image]

If I try to give this combined dataset as input to my network (which has two inputs and one output) I get the following error message:

```
>> net = trainNetwork(imdsCombined,lgraph_1,options);
Error using trainNetwork (line 170)
Invalid training data for multiple-input network. For a network with 2 inputs and 1 output, the datastore read function must
return an M-by-3 cell array, but it returns an M-by-2 cell array.
```

I am using R2019b by the way.

So, is there a way to insert the labels column onto the cell arrays read from the image datastore? Or is there something else I need to do?

Thanks for all the help.

Regards,